# When I read a file of 1 million urls having size of 17 mb, my program occupies size of 163 mb

Tags: c++, file, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am reading the file in the following way.

```
std::vector<std::string> urlList;
std::ifstream infile("top1m.txt");
std::string line;
std::cout << "Loading urls from file" << std::endl;
for (int offset = 0; offset < _urlCount; offset++) {  //_urlCount=1000000
    std::getline(infile, line);
    if (!line.empty()){
        if (line.back() == '\r')
            line.erase(line.length() - 1, std::string::npos);
    }
    urlList.push_back(std::string("http://").append(line));
}
inflie.close();
```

The top1m.txt is of 17 mb.
Before reading the file, my .exe is of just 6 mb.
What am I doing wrong and how to reduce the memory occupied by the program?

Comment: How do you check how much memory your process uses?

Comment: I see it in the task manager. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question but when you want to remove the last character of a `std::string` it's much simpler to just say `line.pop_back();`

Comment: 1. Task Manager is notoriously unreliable on memory usage. 2. If no other program is competing for the resource, Windows might not care to immediately reclaim freed memory.

Comment: Task Manager's `Working set` column might make interesting reading.  It's available (as an option) in the `Details` tab.  Voted up (sigh).  What's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know the _urlCount value before you start the loop, the simplest way you can save memory is to reserve the elements of the vector before you start the loop, using this line:

```
urlList.reserve(_urlCount);
```

The reason this will save a huge amount of memory is because any implementation of vector works by reserving an initial small number of elements, typically the first time it becomes non-empty, then each time push_back would exceed the storage capacity of the vector it allocates a larger buffer with capacity that is some constant times the old capacity (sometimes this constant is 2, but that varies between implementations) then it copies the existing elements from the old buffer to the new buffer before adding the new element.  The old buffers often get left around in memory as candidates for reuse.

So lets suppose the capacity chosen for the original size is 8 elements and the growth factor is 2, and ignore the malloc overhead but assume that the smaller buffers are not getting reused, at least not by the point at which you check the size of your program.

When you have 1 string, the first vector body has capacity for 8 strings.
By the time you have 8+1 strings, the new vector body has capacity for 2*8 but you still have (as freed memory) the old buffer for the old vector body with capacity for 8.

By the time you have 1,000,000 strings you potentially have the following buffers in memory:

1 used buffer for a vector body with capacity for 2 ** 20 strings

1 free buffer with capacity for 2 ** 19 strings

1 free buffer with capacity for 2 ** 18 strings

...

1 free buffer with capacity for 8 strings

Of course it is possible that some of these smaller buffers could get reused at some point, and I just made up the initial capacity of 8 and used a growth factor of 2 because I saw it on some old implementation of std::vector and I am also ignoring the details about the implementation of std::string but you get the idea.

When you reserve space for 1,000,000 strings up front you will get just the one large buffer for the vector body.  Given the size of the strings, you will still have 1,000,000 smaller buffers associated with the URL strings, and you could save massive amounts of space by not using std::string but that is another story and is not addressed in this answer.